# How to handle the transition from a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, uiactionsheet

**Scenario:** I'm trying to implement something similar to iPhone's Contacts book app for deleting a contact.  In the iPhone's Contacts app, to delete a contact, one would go to the 'All Contacts' scene and click on a contact (e.g. 'Test Delete'), then click on the 'Edit' button and scroll down the bottom to find the 'Delete' button.  Once the 'Delete' button is clicked, a UIActionSheet with 'Delete' and 'Cancel' buttons are presented, and one can click on 'Delete' to delete the contact, AND the Contacts app automatically return to the 'All Contacts' scene.

**Problem:** In my app, I added a 'Delete' button and the code to launch a UIActionSheet:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

and add the delegate:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSLog(@"actionSheet is called: clicked button - %ld, %@", (long)buttonIndex, [self.parentViewController description]); }
```

These all worked OK.  Just like the Contacts app, this is done on an 'Edit' scene to remove an item, and I want to transition from this 'Edit' scene back to the 'All Items' scene, with the item being edited removed from the 'All Items' scene. I don't know how to do the transition -- that's the problem.

**Question:** how to implement the delegate (or anything else) so that my app just behaves like the iPhone's Contacts app to transition from the 'Edit' scene back the 'All Contacts' scene?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex) /// here you can get destructiveButton tapped
    {
         [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // and got to previous viewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will also need to get the key to the item being edited back to the 'All Items' scene so that it can be deleted from the all items list.

Comment: I think one of the reasons why iPatel's code didn't 'work' is because the 'Edit' scene is modal, so it doesn't have a root view controller associated with it.  Note that there are 3 scenes involved: 1). All Contacts; 2). Display a Contact; 3). Edit a Contact.  Now for delete, it needs to go from 'Edit a Contact' to 'All Contacts' (and delete the contact on it, too).